# How to count 'all less than' in Access?

Tags: ms-access, count

My Access table has product name and price for each record. I want to get a count of all records with price less than a current record's price. How do I use the count function to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access type:

```
SELECT Table1.ID, DCount("*","Table1","Price<" & [Price]) AS NumCheaper
FROM Table1
```

This will show #Error where there is a null price.

More general:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.ANumber, 
      (SELECT Count(*) FROM Table1 b 
       WHERE b.ANumber<a.ANumber) AS Num_Cheaper
FROM Table1 a
```

This will show 0 where there is a null price.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 SELECT COUNT(PRODUCT_ID) WHERE PRICE < [YOUR_CURRENT_PRICE] GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID
```

Comment: The basic rule is to first get a SELECT query that returns all the records you are interested in, then count all of them. If the query returns only records less than a certain price, then counting all of them gives you the result you want. SELECT does its job, and COUNT does its job.